# partially non capital section title

Tags: sectioning, capitalization

I try to do a partially small capital title because of a Name. How would I do that?

A mwe is given below:

```
\documentclass{JAC2003}

\begin{document}
    \section{BIGsmallBIG}
\end{document}
```

leads to:
    BIGSMALLBIG

Classfile: http://sourceforge.net/p/jacow-spms/jacow-templates/ci/master/tree/LaTeX/A4/ -> the jac2003.cls file would be it I think.

Comment: Hi! Could you please give us a link to file `JAC2003.cls` since it is not present in standard distributions. Thanks.

Comment: @tohecz. I updated the question with the link. Sorry completly forgot about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that nothing too complicated is needed for this class:

```
\documentclass{JAC2003}

\begin{document}
    \section{BIG\lowercase{small}BIG $\lowercase{a}=A$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `lowercase`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The class is using `\uppercase`, which is a big mistake: `\MakeUppercase` would have been better.

In order to solve your problem, you get change the definition of `\section` so that exactly the same output is obtained, but with better control on what is uppercased and what isn't. The key is using `\MakeTextUppercase` from the `textcase` package.

```
\documentclass{JAC2003}

\usepackage{textcase}

\makeatletter
\def\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
    {\z@}
    {2.0ex plus 0.8ex minus .1ex}
    {1.0ex plus .2ex}
    {\large\bfseries\boldmath\centering\MakeTextUppercase}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Big\NoCaseChange{Small}Big}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: surely you mean `\MakeTextUppercase` since that's what you used in the example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was referring to the usage of `\uppercase` in the class, which should be `\MakeUppercase`. For the OP's needs, this can be changed into `\MakeTextUppercase`.

Comment: @egreg Actually it cannot, since I'm obliged to use that template. But thank you anyway for your effort.